# What is the shell/open/command proper syntax?

Tags: shell, syntax, batch-file, file-association

I want to tweak my Windows 7 Ultimate OS to make it easier to open .php files on my server. If I just make the file open with iexplore.exe via the open with menu, it will attempt to download the .php file rather than opening it. (I use XAMPP).

I have configured the directories properly for XAMPP.

In the Reg I created

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.php
@tweak.php.open
```

&

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\teak.php.open\shell\open\command
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" localhost/%1
```

However this does not produce the expected result. It does not work like this.

After some debugging I've found that the reason behind this is because the full address of the file is sent by using the variable %1.

i.e.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" localhost/D:\Web Development\xampp\htdocs\form.php

I thought the syntax was the same as in Batch? In batch if you use %1 it will be the name of the file. Which is what I want to get, not the entire path.

I've solved this matter with a rather choppy solution, by redirecting the output to a batch file I've created for parsing the string and sending it to iexplore.exe... Please somebody help me with the syntax or tell me where I can learn the proper syntax. (I'm not sure what the name of this type of language is called.... batch or shell or what. :S)

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  Voted to close / migrate the question to SuperUser.com ... where it is (at least) on-topic.

Comment: It is. He's programming a command using command line processor language.

Comment: Can someone please explain what this "language" is (the name so I can Google it) and where I can learn about it?

Comment: type `help` at command prompt, you'll see the list of commands, then `help <command name>` gives you the syntax. The most enlightening ones are `help call`, `help cmd`, `help for`, `help set`

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar (to a degree) with command prompt and even some batch, but I got confused when my attempts did not work. %1 should have been the filename only, but it passed the whole path... Hahaha, I was starting to think it wasn't batch, but some other mysterious language. :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "localhost/%~nx1"
```

P.S. No, i doesn't seem to work directly, you have to put this line into a batch file.

Here's the workaround, put this line into registry:

```
cmd /c "for %%a in ("%1") do "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "localhost/%%~nxa""
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this in the command key but it does not function properly? I did manage to make a work around by using a batch file, but I did not manage to find a way to do it directly. Panda, you are using a lot of foreign syntax to me, such as the ^ marks and %%~nxa^  ... I would like to learn and understand this, what is this language called? It's different from batch is it not?

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd - It was a problem with spaces and parentheses, I corrected the command. As for the syntax - it's regular batch file syntax, `^` escapes the next character so that it loses its special function. I escaped quotes inside the literal string, otherwise they would be treated as end of string, you need to escape parens (probably ony closing ones, but it wouldn't hurt to escape both) - otherwise they're marking nested program block. I don't know why you need to escape spaces, just came by it by trial and error. `%%~nxa` means take only name and extension from the file name in `%%a`

Comment: I changed it a bit to make it work. cmd /c "for %%a in (^"%1^") do "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" localhost/%%~nxa"

Comment: Also @panda-34 that is SUCH an awesome syntax line. I am extremely happy with it. I'm embarrassed to show you the batch file I made to do the job. Thanks a lot for the help. One thing I don't understand though is why the "for %%a in (%1)" I am having a hard time understanding how you incorporated a for statement (which is genius by the way... but I want to understand it).

Comment: Yes, you're right to remove all `^`. I actually solved a problem that I myself created. You don't need to escape anything in cmd /c parameter, cmd is smart enough. I corrected the answer. You better keep quotes around `localhost/%%~nxa`, though, just in case there's some weird character in the filename.

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd, if this was a command in batch file you could get filename from its argument with a simple %~nx1, as was my first proposal. This `~nx` stuff works only with command line arguments (%1, %2...) and `for` loop variables. If we can't use the former - let's use the latter, `for %%a in ("%1")` here means `%%a=%1`

Comment: Yes that's a good point about keeping quotes around the localhost/%%~nxa I see what you're saying... You used the for statement, not for looping, but just for the sole reason of making %%a=%1, and all in one nice clean line, well done. Panda, thanks for taking the time to explain this to me. Cheers.